# How can I slide to index from state variable for SwiperJs in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, web, swiper.js

Currently, I'm implemented reactjs component which show per view at 5 items and using `loop` mode from SwiperJS.

Each item can clickable and it will set `useState` after click for keep current selecting index.

The feature that I need is when current selecting index changed, slider(swiper) will slide to that index.

but the problem is when I using `slideToLoop` method. The direction when it slide to index is incorrect. and it always slide a slider even that item index already showed on viewport.